# Cambiar SQL con condición IF ELSE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Necesito saber cómo hacer que cuando hago una consulta a la base de datos primero haga unas preguntas. Como por ejemplo, `if ($_POST['tipo'] == 0)` mostrar una consulta, y un `else` será otra consulta.... ¿Eso se puede hacer?

La consulta que tengo ahora es la siguiente:

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT
    productos.id,     productos.producto,   productos.imagen,
    productos.alias,  posibles.idproducto,  posibles.tipo,
    posibles.entrada, posibles.mensualidad, posibles.final,
    posibles.total
FROM productos, posibles
WHERE productos.id = posibles.idproducto
    AND posibles.idproducto = $id
    AND posibles.tipo = $tip
ORDER BY posibles.final $orden");

mysqli_set_charset("utf8");

while($res = $results->fetch_array()) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por supuesto, sería algo así:

```
//Creas una variable global para guardar el resultado
$result = null;

//Aqui hago la condicción
if($_POST['tipo'] == 0){
    $result = $mysqli->query("la consulta que sea");
}else{
    $result = $mysqli->query("La otra consulta que sea");
}

//Y aquí, una vez tengo cargado el result con la query que sea, 
//hago el while para recorrer las respuestas
while($res = $result->fetch_array()) {
    //Codigo que sea aqui...
}
```

Espero que se haya entendido :)

Comment: Es estupendo!!! funciona perfecto muchisimas gracias!